# How to add algorithm in beamer?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, presentations

i am trying to add algorithm pseudo code in my beamer presentation by simply copy and pasting the code which i have used in writing my paper as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> { 
\usetheme{Madrid} 
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}  

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Text Summarization Algorithm}\label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{Summary Construction}{}\newline
        \textbf{Input:} Text Document.\newline
        \textbf{Output:} Summary sentences.
        \State{Creating information table from a text document.}
        \State{Generate matrices.}
        \State {\textbf{Call Pocedure:} Reduct Construction \textbf{[Algorithm 2]}}
        \State {\textbf{Return:} Summary sentences}
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
    \label{alg_1}
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The error i am getting is `Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}`. I would appreciate if someone can help me solving this issue.

Comment: Try adding the `fragile` option to the frame as in `\begin{frame}[fragile]`

Comment: this change lead to another error `Undefined control sequence. \Procedure`. However previous error `\end{frame}` is resolved.

Comment: The code you provided is insufficient to understand the possible cause of the error. We need at the very least to see the preamble so we know which packages you included (they are the ones that should be defining the missing `\Procedure`). Please *do not underestimate the value of a complete minimal example*.

Comment: i've updated the code, i hope you will get what u want in order to find the cause of error.

Comment: I get a `file ended while scanning use of \next`. Please reduce your code to the minimum and try to get some code which gives us the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 8):

Full minimal example please. This compiles just fine under TeX Live 2015.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Text Summarization Algorithm}\label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{Summary Construction}{}\newline
        \textbf{Input:} Text Document.\newline
        \textbf{Output:} Summary sentences.
        \State{Creating information table from a text document.}
        \State{Generate matrices.}
        \State {\textbf{Call Pocedure:} Reduct Construction \textbf{[Algorithm 2]}}
        \State {\textbf{Return:} Summary sentences}
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
    \label{alg_1}
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have 30 slides but error is in this frame only `document class` and `packages` are all included.

Comment: i've updated the code, i hope you will get what u want in order to find the cause of error.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad If I replace the `algorithmic` package in your code with `algpseudocode` as in daleif's answer, it works fine.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks alot for the help, error is resolved now.